# EC2 added memory is not reflecting in the diskspace

Tags: partitioning, amazon-ec2

I have added some extra space to my EC2 instance and resized the filesystem following AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

Not sure what went wrong but my disk size is showing up correctly when I try `df -h` but the used space is wrong and not sure why my newly added disk space is showing up occupied.

`ncdu` is showing up the correct used space.

How can I fix and add space to my existing filesystem?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Start by looking at what is filling up in /var ...

Comment: @SorenA if you calculate the total disk space used, it will be less then 30GB, but I do have 97GB partition. 
So the used disk space should be around 30%. But its showing up 96% used.
Its not an issue of `/var` occuping space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and fixed it. Diskspace was occupied by the deleted log file whose reference was kept by a process (in my case PHP).

Used `lsof +L1` to check which process was keeping the reference and then run `kill -9 processID` to terminate the process and it will release the memory as well.